# Inputting CSV Data to specific columns in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I have table *Emp* which have primary key which is auto increment. My *csv* file has 2 columns and table *Emp* has 3 columns(Autoincrement primary key and 2 columns from *csv* file).

I have below code:

```py
import pandas as pd, csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("CleanData.db")
cur = con.cursor()

a_file = open("EmpC.csv")
rows = csv.reader(a_file)

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO emp VALUES (?, ?)", rows)

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
print(cur.fetchall())

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your query with named columns:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO emp (column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)", rows)
```

where `column1` and `column2` are the two non-autoincrement column names.